# I want to change the tracking/comparison of the upstream branch

Tags: git, github, fork, upstream

I'm new to forking and trying to wrap my head around the process.
I have an original repo "Main Repo" which I've forked and cloned.
There's a branch "branch-A" on Main Repo that I want to make contributions to.
So far these are the steps I've run:

```sh
git clone <forked-repo>
git remote add upstream <original-repo>
git checkout -b feature-branch
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/branch-A
*make some codes changes*
*commit changes*
git push origin feature-branch
```

When I go back to Github and select the branch I just committed, it shows "This branch is x commits ahead of **master**" but I want it to show how many commits ahead/behind I am off **branch-A**. What commands do I need to run to do that? Thanks!

Comment: GitHub always shows your branch in relation to the default branch of the _GitHub_ repository (usually `main` or `master`). Changing the upstream branch locally will have no effect on GitHub's UI.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to get GitHub to show you what you want, but it is easy enough in command-line Git.  Just remember that the command line works on *your* repository, not on any repository over on GitHub, so you'll need to be sure to have your repository synchronized with the GitHub-side ones (via `git fetch` and/or `git push` as needed).

Suppose that you'd like to compare the name `origin/feature-branch` (as seen in your Git repository, representing your Git's memory of `origin`'s `feature-branch) to the name` upstream/branch-A`(your Git's memory of`upstream`'s` branch-A`).  You can do:

```
git rev-list --count upstream/branch-A..origin/feature-branch
```

The two-dot notation here means: *Find commits that are **reachable** by starting with whichever commit `origin/feature-branch` names, and look at those commits, but stop looking when you get to a commit reachable from `upstream/branch-A`.*  You can use this construct with many Git commands, including `git log`:

```
git log upstream/branch-A..origin/feature-branch
```

Here, we're using it with `git rev-list`, which is a lot *like* `git log`—they're kind of sister commands—except that `rev-list` simply lists the commit hash IDs (this is intended for feeding to other Git programs).  With the `--count` option, instead of *listing* the hash IDs, it *counts* them.  So this gives a count of commits that are reachable from `origin/feature-branch`, but *not* reachable from `upstream/branch-A`, and that's your "ahead of" count.

#### Additional information

There's also a count of commits reachable from `upstream/branch-A` but not reachable from `origin/feature-branch`.  We can get this with:

```
git rev-list --count origin/feature-branch..upstream/branch-A
```

Note that the placement of the two names around the `..` special-character-sequence is swapped.  Given what you've done recently, you can typically expect this count to be zero: that is, there are no such commits.

You can get both counts at once using `git rev-list --left-right` and the *three*-dot syntax, `upstream/branch-A...origin/feature-branch` for instance, but we'll leave that for later.

For (much) more on the concept of *reachable commits*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).